# UITableView Seems to reloadData automatically (tabbar controller) iOS8?

Tags: uitableview, ios8, reloaddata, viewwillappear

I can't prevent my tableview to reload its datas when I switch controller with the tabbarController.
My cells are pretty heavy to load and no new datas have been downloaded so there is no need to reload the tableview except freezing the UI for less than half a second... 
Have you also noticed this since iOS8 ( I checked on iOS7 and this doesn't happened)

thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post the code where you configure / load your tableView ?

Comment: no code in particlular, Tableview added from IB. _tableView.delegate = self & _tableView.datasource = self in viewdidload.

Answer (score 0):

try to override viewWillAppear and don't call super